# How to determine someone's star sign from their birthday using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to know how to determine someone's star sign from their birthday using Rails.

I thought I could have a drop-down/select menu and allow the user to choose their star sign, or have a text field so they can type it in, but I think automatically displaying their star sign using the stored birthday in the DB is more productive.

What would be the easiest and cleanest way to do this?

Comment: It is always better to rely on information the user stored as their preference, than making them re-enter it. And, if using a limited set of choices is a possibility, use those, in a select or pop-up, rather than allow the user to enter something. Users mistype, misspell, deliberately try to hack the system, so by reducing the chance for them to screw up you often improve their experience using your code.

Comment: I hope this is merely a programming exercise! http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2442/does-astrology-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which zodiac (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zodiac) ? You do know that zodiac dates are not fixed ? :)

https://github.com/7even/zodiac should the one you are looking for. See their README for more details. In the future, you can try searching rubygems.org, like so http://rubygems.org/search?query=zodiac

If you don't need a gem, a case statement on the dob in the model should suffice

Comment: You can search for gems using `gem search zodiac -r` from the command-line very easily too.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a [zodiac](https://github.com/7even/zodiac) gem for that

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is hardly related to rails, it's rather a general programming question. Wouldn't one case statement with 12 branches be just fine?